# How to set admin theme for a route?

Tags: 8, routes

According to [Drupal handbook](https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643) route definition accepts parameter called `_theme`. Unfortunately this parameter is documented as *"TODO"*.

Can this be used to force admin theme for the route? Is it possible to inject config parameter with admin theme name here?

It appears that other solution is to use [Theme negotiator](https://www.drupal.org/node/2158619) however the `_theme` parameter looks very tempting and way simpler to use.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking for the _admin_route option:

```
aggregator.feed_add:
  path: '/aggregator/sources/add'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\aggregator\Controller\AggregatorController::feedAdd'
    _title: 'Add feed'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer news feeds'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

Comment: Yet another undocumented D8 feature.

Comment: Documentation might not be so great yet for D8 but change records are: https://www.drupal.org/node/2224207. Always search there if you know how something worked in D7 (found by seaching for "admin path"). https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/routing seems like a good place (subpage or so) to document this, looking forward to the documentation you'll write about this :)

Comment: so does _admin_route just change it so it uses the default theme instead of the admin one?

Comment: I get a InvalidArgumentException: Routing requirement for "options" must be a string. when attempting to use this solution

Answer (score 5):

```
module.myroute:
  path: '/path/path2'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\module\Controller\MyController::add'
    _title: 'Add element'
  options:
    _admin_route: 'TRUE'
```

You need to use ' ' around TRUE, if not,  you will get 'InvalidArgumentException: Routing requirement for "options" must be a string'

Comment: Example here shows it without quotes: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes so I don't think it's necessary anymore.