# How to define frontend theme (non-admin) for a given node tab route?

Tags: routes, navigation

In my custom module I want to define a new tab associated with nodes. I have my own custom route file with the required definitions and a Links file to make sure the new route will be displayed as a node tab.

Everything works as planned, except that... The content of my custom page is wrapped in admin theme, not the website frontend theme.

I have found other threads where people ask the opposite question: 'how to enforce admin theme'? In those situations, it looks like that by setting '**_admin_route: TRUE**' on the route file will do the trick. More on this here:

[How to set admin theme for a route?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185266/how-to-set-admin-theme-for-a-route)

I thought I would be able to achieve what I want by setting '**_admin_route: FALSE**', but it doesn't work. Frontend theme doesn't show, admin theme still kicks in.

This is my modulename.route.yml file:

```
modulename.node.custom_tab:
  path: '/node/{node}/custom-tab'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Custom tab Content'
    _controller: '\Drupal\bti\Controller\MyTabController::pageContent'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    _admin_route: FALSE
    parameters:
      node:
        type: entity:node
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\bti\Controller\MyTabController::access'
```

And this is my modulename.links.task.yml file:

```
entity.node.custom_tab:
  route_name: modulename.node.custom_tab
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: 'Custom tab'
  weight: 50
  options:
    attributes:
      class:
        - 'my-custom-class'
```

So, to sum up: how can I make the new custom page in a node tab be displayed with theme defined for the frontend, not the admin theme? Thank you!

**Edit 1**

---

Is it possible that what I am looking for is the attribute '_theme' inside 'options'? It is marked as TODO here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/structure-of-routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_node_operation_route` option respect the **Use the administration theme when editing or creating content**, if you want to explicitly disable admin theme for this node-related page don't use `_node_operation_route`

The `_node_operation_route` option overrides `_admin_route` https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21EventSubscriber%21NodeAdminRouteSubscriber.php/function/NodeAdminRouteSubscriber%3A%3AalterRoutes/8.8.x

Comment: Ahhhh, great, man, fantastic and many thanks. I simply removed **_node_operation_route** and **_admin_route** from my route file and all works as expected.